# Executing SQL Script via Ant

Tags: oracle, ant

I have a working SQL Script, `.sql` file for Oracle which works fine when I execute from SQL Developer but now I am trying to invoke same from ANT Script it is throwing me lot of errors related to syntax.

Can anyone help me what all things I need to consider when I am targeting to execute sql script via ant?

Eg. A statement below from the `.sql` file works very fine from SQL Developer but Ant is throwing Syntax Error.

```
myuser@myserver:/app/myapp/myAnt/install $ ant TestSQL
Buildfile: /app/myapp/myAnt/install/build.xml

TestSQL:
      [sql] Executing resource: /app/myapp/myAnt/install/config/SQL/CleanDB.sql
      [sql] Failed to execute:  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BUILD FAILED
/app/myapp/myAnt/install/build.xml:32: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: Fehlende oder ungültige Option
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execSQL(SQLExec.java:775)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.runStatements(SQLExec.java:745)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.runTransaction(SQLExec.java:1055)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.access$000(SQLExec.java:985)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:653)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Total time: 1 second

Comment: how are to trying to run? , you can wrap you sql statement inside a file & run as shell script call via `exec` ant task?

Comment: It would be nice if you could show both Ant and SQL scripts. Also for information, "Fehlende oder ungültige Option" thranslates in English to "Missing or invalid option", at least according to Google translate.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `set SERVEROUTPUT ON` is a SQL*Plus command and not an SQL statement, and that the JDBC driver that the Ant `sql` task uses does not understand it.

So instead, you might need to invoke PL/SQL from Ant with an `exec`task, similarly to this:

```
<exec executable="${oracle.bin.dir}/sqlplus" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="${username}/${password}@${tns_alias}"/>
  <arg value="@${script.path}/my_script.sql"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: To be picky, `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` isn't PL/SQL, it's a SQL\*Plus command. Other tools such as SQL Developer may also understand it.  However, it doesn't change the fact that using an `exec` task in the Ant buildfile to run SQL\*Plus, as you suggest, is the way to go.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for correcting me. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL script is not added, but I assume that using **delimiter** and **delimitertype** attributes may help as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48606931/6792588).

Not sure about the **exec** task mentioned above, since it is not a generic solution (I suggest to use SQL Ant task whenever possible to support different database providers).

Goodluck