# sql script execution fails when called using ANT SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ant

There is a SQL file which contains some Transact SQL statements in it and some plain table queries as follows:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SYSTEM_PROPERTIES] WHERE SYS_PROP = 'ABC')
BEGIN
DECLARE @SYS_PROP_ID INT;
INSERT INTO SYSTEM_PROPERTIES (...,....,...) values ('...','...','...');
SELECT    -------;
INSERT INTO ------;
END
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TEMPLATE] WHERE TPL_NAME='....' )
UPDATE [dbo].[TEMPLATE] SET [...] = 'Y' WHERE TPL_NAME='.....'
GO
```

When I execute this script directly on the database, it works fine. When the same script is called through an ANT SQL task it fails with the following error:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'INT'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
```

This is the Ant task:

```
<sql   driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"   url="---------"
userid="--"   password="---"  keepformat="true" print="true" >
 <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="/lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
 </classpath>
<transaction  src="${dbscript.location}/dbscript.sql"/>
</sql>
```

Why is the script failing when called from ANT SQL?

Comment: @billinkc, thank you for the response. The error I am seeing is right at the beginning of script (line 3) in the script above. How will removing GO help in that case?

Comment: My assumption is that GO, which is not part of TSQL but instead is interpreted specially in the command tools (sqlcmd/ssms) is fouling up the works. Which would explain why it works when executed directly but not here. It's a theory, which is why I commented instead of answering

Comment: @billinkc, I tried removing the GO from the script. Still end up with the same error. Any other ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: Well that's disappointing... It's been over a decade since I've dealt with ANT so I'm fairly tapped out at this point. The only thing that sounds like it might of interest is the failing method, `getNextResult` might be choking because it expects a result and perhaps the channel is returning non-result-like-things. If you being your script with `SET NOCOUNT ON` does that introduce any magic?

Answer (score 2):

After spending a lot of time, I finally was able to resolve the issue. When calling any Transact SQL statements through an ANT SQL task, the ";" delimiters should NOT be specified. Having these delimiters will not cause any problem when executing the SQL statements from SQL Management studio or sqlcmd.
Also, as pointed out in the comments above, GO statement is also not acceptable when running the script through ANT SQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Ant task supports the following attributes which allow you to use semicolon in your script, and actually let you run complex scripts such as PL/SQL or Stored Procedures:

- delimiter
- delimitertype

Use them together in your task like this:

```
<sql ...
    delimiter="/"
    delimitertype="row"
    ... 
/>
```

In this example any ';' will be replaced by '/'

For more details check ANT docs [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html)